# Почему JS не видит переменную?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите разобраться, изучаю JS, столкнулся со следующей проблемой в коде:

```
function fieldsShowWhenObjChanged() {
        var filterObjTypeVal = $('#FilterObjectType').val();
        $('#case_number').css('display', filterObjTypeVal == "CLAIM" ? '' : 'none');
        $('#srv_services').css('display', filterObjTypeVal == "SRV_SERVICE" ? '' : 'none');

        if (filterObjTypeVal == "SRV_SERVICE") {
        let takeUnPublishedServices = true;
        $("#FilterServiceCode").AjaxMultipleSelectHierarchy({
            selectAllText: "Выбрать все Услуги",
            selectedAll: "Выбраны все Услуги",
            placeholder: 'Выберите Услуги',
            includeParent: true,
            baseClass: "ms",
            link: '@Url.Action(nameof(ManageController.GetItems))',
            query: {
                type: "services_with_subservices",
                takeUnPublishedServices: takeUnPublishedServices,
            },
            onItemCreate: function ($item) {
                sliceText($item.find('div').addClass('sliceText_v2'));
            },
        });
        $("#IsCheckTakeUnPublishedServices").prop('checked', takeUnPublishedServices);
        }

    }
```

в данном случаи ошибка не возникает, так как переменная `let takeUnPublishedServices = true` объявлена явно, но если переписать код вот так, то будет ругаться, что не видит переменную, почему, я ведь ей в `query` передаю то-же самое значение, в чем разница между передачей значения так и объявлением переменной?

```
function fieldsShowWhenObjChanged() {
        var filterObjTypeVal = $('#FilterObjectType').val();
        $('#case_number').css('display', filterObjTypeVal == "CLAIM" ? '' : 'none');
        $('#srv_services').css('display', filterObjTypeVal == "SRV_SERVICE" ? '' : 'none');

        if (filterObjTypeVal == "SRV_SERVICE") {
        $("#FilterServiceCode").AjaxMultipleSelectHierarchy({
            selectAllText: "Выбрать все Услуги",
            selectedAll: "Выбраны все Услуги",
            placeholder: 'Выберите Услуги',
            includeParent: true,
            baseClass: "ms",
            link: '@Url.Action(nameof(ManageController.GetItems))',
            query: {
                type: "services_with_subservices",
                takeUnPublishedServices: true,
            },
            onItemCreate: function ($item) {
                sliceText($item.find('div').addClass('sliceText_v2'));
            },
        });
        $("#IsCheckTakeUnPublishedServices").prop('checked', takeUnPublishedServices);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Что именно за ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что ошибка возникает на строке

```
 $("#IsCheckTakeUnPublishedServices").prop('checked', takeUnPublishedServices);
```

Оно и не удивительно. Ведь переменная `takeUnPublishedServices` не объявлена.

Если вы думаете, что тут:

```
query: {
    type: "services_with_subservices",
    takeUnPublishedServices: true,
},
```

вы объявляете переменую, то это не так. Вы передаёте в свойство `query` объект с ключами у которых имя `type` и `takeUnPublishedServices`. Никакого объявления переменных тут нет.

Пример

```
let test = {
    field1: 555,
    field5: 'testy'
}
```

Вы же не будете утверждать, что тут объявляются переменные `field1` и `field5` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ругается на строчку

```
 $("#IsCheckTakeUnPublishedServices").prop('checked', takeUnPublishedServices);
```

в которой и используется переменная, определение которой ты убрал.

Так как переменная не объявлена - видишь ошибку об этом.

Если убрать эту строчку, то и ошибка пропадет, что покажет отсутствие разница между передачей значения напрямую либо в виде переменной